# Show that $\sum (-1)^{n+1}\frac{\log(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to show $$\sum (-1)^{n+1}\frac{\log(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}$$ is convergent.

Attempt: Let $u_n=\frac{\log(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}$.

Want to use Libnitz test.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}u_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}=0 ~(By~ L~ Hospital ~Rule)$$

Now how to show that ${u_n}$ is monotonic decreasing? Please solve.

Comment: More direct: Just prove $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{\log(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}$ converges

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen please in details

Comment: $\log(n)= 2 \log( \sqrt{n}) \le 2\sqrt{n}$ for all $n$, thus $$\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2} \le 2\sum_{n \ge 1} n^{-3/2} <+\infty$$ Hence your series converges absolutely, hence it converges in the usual sense.

Comment: $\log( \sqrt{n}) \le \sqrt{n}$ How to show this

Comment: It's weaker than the well known ineq $$\ln(1+x) \le x \forall x \ge 0$$ Each one of two can be proven by considering derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{\log (x+1)}{(x+1)^2}$, then $f(x)' = \frac{-2\ln (x+1)+1}{\ln (10)(x+1)^3}$, it is clear that when $x \geq 2$, we always have $\ln(x+1)>0$, hence $f(x)'<0$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$f(x)=\frac{\log(x+1)}{(x+1)^2}$$
Then
$$f'(x)=\frac{x+1-2(x+1)\log(x+1)}{(x+1)^4}.$$
Let
$$g(x)=x+1-2(x+1)\log(x+1)$$
then
$$g'(x)=-1-2\log(x+1) \leq 0$$ for each $x \ge 0.$
Hence $g$ is decreasing and finishing to be $ \leq 0.$
In conclusion, $f'(x) \leq 0.$